# Erro no PHP: "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare()"

Tags: php, mysql

Quando tento executar o `SELECT` no servidor acusa essa msg: `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in blog.php on line 97`
a linha referida é essa:

```
$readPost = $db->prepare($postagemRead);
```

mais um pouco assim esta assim:

```
$pg = 1;
    $limite = 5;
    $inicio = ($pg * $limite) - $limite;

    $postagemRead = "SELECT * FROM postagem ORDER BY datapost DESC LIMIT :inicio,:limite";
    try{
            $readPost = $db->prepare($postagemRead);
```

o arquivo de conexão é esse:

```
<?php 
try{
        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost;charset=utf8;","root","");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $e -> getMessage();
    }   
?>
```

não vejo o problema visto executo isso no servidor local(wamp server) e roda normal, mas no host da esse erro o que pode ser?

Erro:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in
>   /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php:3 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php(3):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=85...', 'root', '') #1
>   /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/padrao.php(1):
>   require_once('/home/vhosts/mo...') #2 {main}' in
>   /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php:5 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/padrao.php(1): require_once() #1 {main}
>   thrown in /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php on line 5

Comment: A linha `$e->getMessage()` não faz absolutamente nada dentro desse `catch`. Você precisa colocar um echo/die ou fazer algum tratamento no `catch`, caso contrário o código vai continuar executando normalmente mesmo se houver algum erro na conexão.

Comment: Erro  'exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=85...', 'root', '') #1 /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/padrao.php(1): require_once('/home/vhosts/mo...') #2 {main}' in /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/padrao.php(1): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php on line 5

Answer (score 2):

1. O objeto de conexão não foi salvo na variável `$db`. Portanto, a função `prepare` não existe em `$db`. Isto porque...
2. ...você não está explodindo o erro, ou seja, o `try {} catch()` não está **parando** seu código e ele está continuando, dando a ilusão de que `$db` existe.

   Correto:

   ```
   try
   {
       $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost;charset=utf8;","root","");
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       throw new PDOException($e);
   }
   ```

Após explodir o erro, verá qual a mensagem na falha da conexão em `new PDO`. Não vendo mais erros, a variável `$db` existirá corretamente e portanto, `$db->prepare($postagemRead);` **funcionará**.

**Dica**

Provavelmente o user `root` e a senha `""` não existem no `host` (servidor remoto).

Comment: Qual o sentido de lançar a mesma exceção que você acabou de capturar?

Comment: retirei o `root` e `""` `$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost;charset=utf8;");` porem ainda da erro

Comment: mudei apenas para `print $e` e deu essa msg:  exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/config.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=85...') #1 /home/vhosts/molbe.freetzi.com/padrao.php(1): require_once('/home/vhosts/mo...') #2 {main}

Comment: @HebertdeLima, não é para "retirar", é para corrigir, pois no seu servidor remoto o usuário e a senha muito provavelmente são diferentes. Você colou o `try {... }` que coloquei no post? Ele lança o erro correspondente e você vê qual é o problema na conexão.

Comment: vou ver com o host.

Answer (score -2):

Tente utilizar um RETURN após instanciar a conexão, assim:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost;charset=utf8;","root","");
return $db;
```

caso a conexão esteja em uma classe e você instancie esta classe, crie uma variavel pública $conn por exemplo, desta maneira:

```
class Conexao {

    public $conn;

    try{
        $this->conn = "aqui sua linha de conexao";
        return $this->conn;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

espero ter ajudado.